# Упростить логику подсчета (не отвеченых сообщений, подсчет cnt)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой, на сайте есть служба поддержки, где ведется переписка с пользователем и админом. 
Появилась проблема, что вся админка стала очень долго грузиться, была выявлена причина, долгую загрузку давал метод подсчета (количества не отвеченных сообщений), а так как он отображается на любой странице в админке, то любая страница начала грузиться более 5 секунд.

Ниже приведу кусок кода с модели и контроллера, что бы увидеть общую картину:

Контроллер:

```
function getCount()
{
    $cnt = model_support::getUnreadAdmin();

    if($cnt > 0)
    {
        echo '<span class="">'.$cnt.'</span>';
    }
}
```

Модель: (есть два варианта подсчета, но один из них работает быстрее но считает не совсем верно, он будет подписан как "вариант 2")

Вариант1

```
public static function getUnreadAdmin()
{
    $list = self::getAdminList();

    $cnt = 0;
    foreach($list as $k)
    {
        $last = $k->getLastMessage();
        if($last['author_type'] == 'user' and !$last['admin_readed'])
            $cnt++;
    }

    return $cnt;
}
```

Вариант 2

```
public static function getUnreadAdmin()
{
    $stmt = database::query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM support  ORDER BY created_at DESC) s  GROUP BY user_id) ss  WHERE admin_readed=0 AND author_type='user'");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['cnt'];
}
```

В первом варианте в метод вызывается `getAdminList()` 
Вот эта функция:

```
public static function getAdminList()
{
    $list = database::i()->support()->order('created_at DESC')
            ->select('support.*, COUNT(support.id) as cnt')
            ->group('user_id')
            // ->order('created_at DESC')->limit(10)
            ->order('created_at DESC')
            ->fetchPairs('id');

    uasort($list, function($a, $b){
        // return ($a->getLastMessage()['author_type'] == 'user') ? -1 : 1;
        return ($a->getLastMessage()['created_at'] > $b->getLastMessage()['created_at']) ? -1 : 1;

    });

    // $stmt = database::query("SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM (SELECT * FROM support  ORDER BY created_at DESC) s  GROUP BY user_id order by created_at desc");
    // $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $list;
}
```

Буду рад помощи в этой ситуации, а так же предложению как это еще можно делать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Т. Е. В таблице support подсчитать количество строк с admin_read=0.? Тогда не ясно зачем 3 вложенных select.

Comment: Второй вариант, выводит просто (1) если есть вовсе какое либо количество, не отвеченных сообщений

Comment: Не совсем "подсчитать количество строк с admin_read=0", они еще группируются по id пользователя, что бы отображалось только количество пользователей, от которых есть не прочитанные/ не отвеченные смс, а не количество, всех смс с 0 в поле admin_read

Comment: Select count(user_id) from support where admin_read=0 group by user_id  количество строк это количество пользователей у которых есть хотя бы одно неотвеченное сообщение.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt 
FROM ( SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT * 
    FROM support  
    ORDER BY created_at DESC) s  
  GROUP BY user_id) ss  
WHERE admin_readed=0 
AND author_type='user'` - это кто ж такой [censored] сотворил-то??? Замени на `SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt 
FROM support  
WHERE admin_readed=0 
  AND author_type='user'
GROUP BY user_id;`

Comment: "– Akina" Благодарю Вас за помощь, но увы такой запрос ведет не верный счет( Сделал так: "$stmt = database::query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM support  WHERE admin_readed=0 AND author_type='user'");" = считает каждое новое сообщение которое не было прочитано.